# C++ and RapidJson: Define Value without document

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm using RapidJson to parse Json-Files in my C++ application.

Inside my json file there is an array of float values: `threshs = [0.2, 0.3]`.
This array is stored as an attribute of a `Settings` class. The type is `const Value*`. If I need to access the data I can call `(*settings->threshs)[i].GetFloat()`.

If there is an error while parsing, I want to use default values that are set in `Settings.h`. This smoothly works for `Floats, Integers, bools...`.
Problem is: How can I manually create a `const Value*` without creating a document. So in my header file I want s.th. like:

```
const Value* = {0.2, 0.3};
```

Is this possible?
The only solution I had was to change the type of `thresh` to a vector and at the parsing to loop over the json array and copy the values into the vector

Comment: That's explained in the doc: https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#CreateModifyValues

Comment: I don't see it. I can create an empty array easily, but I need to set the default values. Using s.th. like this a.PushBack(Value().SetInt(42), allocator) requires to create a document

Comment: You don't need to use the Document's allocator. Make a `MemoryPoolAllocator allocator;` and use it in your PushBack call. Just make sure it exists (your allocator) at least until you add your Value to the Document.

Comment: Value a(kArrayType) gives "kArrayType" is not a type. I set "using namespace rapidjson" and "#include <rapidjson/rapidjson.h>", ""#include <rapidjson/document.h>""

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles/runs without issue on my setup:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <rapidjson/allocators.h>
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/prettywriter.h>
#include <rapidjson/rapidjson.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace rapidjson;

    Value val(kArrayType);

    //{
    MemoryPoolAllocator alloc;
    val.PushBack(Value(0.1).Move(), alloc);
    val.PushBack(Value(0.2).Move(), alloc);
    //}

    Document doc;
    doc.SetObject().AddMember("arr", val, doc.GetAllocator());

    StringBuffer sb;
    PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(sb);
    doc.Accept(writer);
    cout << sb.GetString() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "arr": [
        0.1,
        0.2
    ]
}
```

Btw if you uncomment the `{` and `}` the allocator will be destroyed before you can add the `Value` and this is what you'll get:

```
{
    "arr": [
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

On the plus side, it doesn't crash.